# Is it possible to define "identity element" for all binary function in Rust?

Tags: algorithm, rust

##### Background:

I'm working with segment trees on Rust, which require an identity element for operations like finding the minimum or maximum value within a segment.

While defining identity elements is possible for simple functions like `min`, `max` and `+` (and actually it seems to be that there are libraries which enable it like [this](https://docs.rs/alga/0.5.1/alga/general/trait.Identity.html)), it becomes cumbersome for user-defined functions.

##### Put simply:

Is there a way to define an object I that, when used with any binary operator/function which takes arguments of any data type, satisfies the equation `f(I, x) == f(x, I) == x`?

I suspect this might involve concepts like traits, but I'm not entirely sure. Ideally, this `I` object would also be memory-efficient.

Any insights, even if they don't perfectly address my question, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How would you define identity element for operation `f(x, y) == 0`, for example? Or what are the real requirements on these "binary functions"?

Comment: As others have noted, there's no such identity element `I` for all *existing* functions *f*: *S* × *S* → *S*; however, you can create an identity element `I` and derive a *new* function *g*: *T* × *T* → *T*, where *T* = *S* ∪ { `I` }, defined piecewise as follows: (1) g(`I`, *x*) = g(*x*, `I`) = *x*; (2) otherwise, both *x* and *y* must be in *S*, so g(*x*, *y*) = f(*x*, *y*). I don't know Rust, but it wouldn't surprise me at all if you can define a generic function *h*: (*S* × *S* → *S*) → (*T* × *T* → *T*) that takes an *f* and returns such a *g*.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm working with segment trees on Rust, which require an identity element for operations like finding the minimum or maximum value within a segment.

This is not correct. Segment trees in general do not require an identity element; they merely require a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup), that is, a set of objects with an associative binary operator `f`: `f(x, f(y, z)) == f(f(x, y), z)`.

Perhaps your particular library imposes this additional restriction. In that case, consider patching (or rewriting, if there are more issues) it.

If you want to see an example of an implementation which does not have this restriction, [I have one in Lua](https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Lua/blob/main/src/data_structures/segment_tree.lua), which should be fairly easy to port to Rust.

> Is there a way to define an object I that, when used with any binary operator/function which takes arguments of any data type, satisfies the equation `f(I, x) == f(x, I) == x`?

For general binary operators, there definitely is not: Consider the simple counterexample of `f(x, y) = max(x, y) + 1`.

Even if your operator is associative, there need not be an identity - otherwise the distinction between semigroups and monoids (semigroups with identity elements) would be unnecessary. Consider `f = min` on the infinite set of natural numbers. No matter how big you choose `I`, there is always a bigger `I` (well, practically not, due to storage limitations; but I don't think you want to fill up all your storage with a pseudo identity element :P).

And even if there was an identity for all types you happen to be interested in, the Rust compiler can't find it in general; these problems can get pretty arbitrarily complex, if not undecidable.

You can not *find* identity elements; you can only *require* them, for example by requiring an appropriate trait or value to be passed (as the library you're using probably does, hence the question).

---

**TL;DR:** The answer to your question is no. But that is not a problem, because your premise that "segment" trees require an identity element is wrong.